# npm package toggle version?

Tags: node.js, npm

Installed the gitbook and gitbook-cli modules, because of an incompatibility problem, multiple versions are installed, how to switch the package version of the module ?

**demo:**

`$ gitbook ls
    GitBook Versions Installed:
        * 3.2.3
        3.1.1
        3.1.0
        3.0.3
        3.0.0
        2.6.7
        2.6.6
        2.6.4
        2.5.0
        2.3.2
        2.1.0
        2.0.0
    Run "gitbook update" to update to the latest version.`

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Documentation,

By default, GitBook CLI will read the gitbook version to use from the book configuration, but you can force a specific version using --gitbook option:

```
$ gitbook build ./mybook --gitbook=2.0.1
```

Therefore change the book config version to the required version or use the above line to force the build.

If you do not need a particular version just uninstall it.

```
$ gitbook uninstall 2.0.1
```